# Why does this program lead to an infinite loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, character

I tried the follow program,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    for(ch='(';ch<='x';ch+='(')
    {
        printf("%c\n",ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expected the program to give the following output,

```
(
P
x
```

(ASCII value of '(' is 40, 'P' is 80, 'x' is 120)

But the program generated an infinite loop instead.

Then I tried another program,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;

    for(ch='(';ch<'x';ch+='(')
    {
        printf("%c\n",ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This time the output was,

```
(
P
```

So I am not able to understand why the,

```
ch<='x'
```

in the first program resulting in a infinite loop.

Comment: What does stepping through the code in a debugger tell you? (It's a very simple loop; stepping through four times should be able to answer this for you, and you'll learn something in the process.)

Comment: Check the data range on `char ch`. It's a signed value. `-128` to `127`. When you add `'('` repeatedly, the values are 40, 80, 120, 160 (whoops, that's now really -96, which is <= 80), etc... You could try using `unsigned char`.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: @lurker this might be a stupid question to ask but why doesn't it just stop at 120?

Comment: Because it will attempt the next iteration. This is how `for` loops work. In the end of the `for(i=0; i<5; i++)`  the `i` will be `5`.

Comment: @lurker I make the sequence 40, 80, 120, -96, -56, -16, 24, 64, 104, -72, -32, 8, 48, 88, -128, -88, -48, -8, 32, 72, 112, -104, -64, -24, 16, 56, 96, -120, -80, -40, 0, then back to 40 and repeat *ad infinitum*. Every time you reach a value greater than 127 you need to subtract 256. The sequence never goes above 120.

Comment: @IanAbbott that is precisely my point if the OP follows the logic beyond my `...` I just didn't feel like doing all of the OP's work for them. ;)

Comment: @user3141208 your loop says to keep looping if the value is `<=` the value of `'x'` which is 120. In other words, if the value is 120, it goes around again!

Answer (score 2):

By the description we can say that `char` is signed in your system (max value of `127` - `SCHAR_MAX`). And when you were adding `'('` to it, you are adding `40` with `120` (results in `160` which is greater than `127`)and results in implementation defined behavior. (In your case supposedly it gets a value smaller than `'x'` that's why the loop doesn't stop - But this is something you can't rely on - *this is implemenation defined behavior).

Also you asked in comment - why doesn't it stop at `120` (in first case)? First of all, your condition is `<='x'` so the value would be incremented when it is equal to the value `'x'`.

Edit: Also one thing - *this is **not** undefined behavior* in that - `char` is promoted to `int` and then result is converted to `char`. This conversion is implementation defined behavior.(There are no arithmetic operations on integer types narrower than `int` that's why the integer promotions are done) [Noted by: Keith Thompson]

Comment: Looks like I had misunderstood how the for loop works. Thanks!

Comment: There's (very probably) no undefined behavior. There are no arithmetic operations on integer types narrower than `int`. A `char` value is promoted to `int`, the addition is performed, and the result is converted back to `char` by the assignment. The result of that conversion, if the result is out of range, is implementation-defined. (And `'('` is of type `int` anyway.)

Comment: @KeithThompson.: Once again - yes I edited. Implementatim defined and undefined is a different thing. Thanks

Comment: Another minor point: Out-of-range integer conversion either yields an implementation-defined value *or* (starting in C99) raises an implementation-defined signal -- which could do just about anything. I don't know of any implementations that do that. Also, it's possible in principle for `int` to be 1 byte (if `CHAR_BIT >= 16`), and then, depending on the numeric value of `'('`, the overflow might have UB. I wouldn't lose much sleep over either possibility.

Comment: @KeithThompson.: `int` ti be 1 byte? `CHAR_BIT = 8` always? And this last part of what you said is right in the sense that yes  if signed integer operation overflows it's UB. But why do we have to `CHAR_BIT>=16` standard says it somewhere?

Comment: @coderredoc: `CHAR_BIT` is required to be *at least* 8, and is exactly 8 on almost all implementations. There are implementations for DSPs that have `CHAR_BIT > 8`. It's possible to have `sizeof (int) == 1`, but only if `CHAR_BIT >= 16` (since `INT_MAX` has to be at least 32767, so it requires at least 16 bits).